# Get select multiple values with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with JQuery, I have a multiple select that i can populate in 2 ways, manually taking some value from another select with a add button, and dynamically, with parsing a json returned from a spring call.
I have no problem to take the value when I add it manually, but, when I populate dynamically the select, the JQuery code doesn't take any value although int the html code there're values in the select.

Here my code:

The empty html selects

```
<div id="enti_disp_box">
  <label>Enti disponibili</label>
  <select id="ente" multiple> </select>
  <button class="btn" onclick="addEnteInBox();" type="button">Aggiungi</button>
</div>

<div id="enti_att_box">
  <label>Enti attivi*</label> 
  <select id="entiAttivi" multiple></select>
  <button class="btn" onclick="removeEnteInBox();" type="button">Rimuovi</button>
</div>
```

JQuery for populate the second select manually

```
function addEnteInBox(){
   var selectedOptions = document.getElementById("ente");
   for (var i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
       var opt = selectedOptions[i];
       if (opt.selected) {
           document.getElementById("entiAttivi").appendChild(opt);
           i--;
       }
   }
}
function removeEnteInBox(){
   var x = document.getElementById("entiAttivi");
   x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
}
```

JQuery for populate the second select dynamically

```
function getEntiByIdUtente(idutente) {
    var action = "getEntiByidUtente";
    var payload = {
        "idUtente": idutente,
        "action": action,
        "token": token
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../service/rest/enti/management_utenti',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        resourceType: 'json',
        success: function(obj, textstatus) {
            obj = obj.trim();
            var json = JSON.parse(obj);
            //parse response
            if (obj.stato == 'error') {
                alert('Errore');
            } else {
                $('#entiAttivi').empty();
                //fetch obj.data and populate table
                $(json.data).each(function() {
                    $("#piva").val(this.piva);
                    $("#codiceipa").val(this.codiceipa);
                    $('#entiAttivi').append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.idente,
                        text: this.ragionesociale
                    }));
                });
            }

            return json;

        },
        error: function(obj, textstatus) {
            alert('Errore di comunicazione col server!');
        }
    });
}
```

JQuery for taking the value of the second select

```
var entiList = $("#entiAttivi").val();
```

Comment: Please add the defination of `addEnteInBox()` `removeEnteInBox()`.

Comment: Are you sure that you call the `val()` after they are appended ?

Comment: @Mayank done, but I'm pretty sure that those functions are ininfluent

Comment: @DanChaltiel yes, the getEntiByIdUtente(idutente) call is at the creation of the page, the val() is called when i press the save button of the form

Answer (score 1):

This line seems to be wrong, it's not working for me

```
$('#entiAttivi').append($('<option>', {
    value: this.idente,
    text: this.ragionesociale
}));
```

would you try replacing by

```
$('#entiAttivi').append($('<option value="' + this.idente + '">' + this.regionesociale + '</option>');
```

The append, is trying to create an option with the json as parent, this is not working. please try my code.

Comment: have you check the generated html for the select, have it the value setted?
Also what is in `entiList` after trying to get the `val()`?

Comment: Still not working, my problem isn't in the population of the select, but when i have to take the value from it, here 2 screen

The html code of the select dynamically populated
[link](http://postimg.org/image/m2qp9h2dz/)

The JQuery when i'm try to do the val()
[link](http://postimg.org/image/sj5lu87zd/)

Comment: the value is in the html also after the val() call

Comment: according jquery:

`The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. In the case of select elements, it returns null when no option is selected and an array containing the value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is possible to select more because the multiple attribute is present.`

could be that there is some options with the same value as says jquery?

Comment: I solved it, the options in the select aren't selected when the val() was called